# Repopulating div with new form/content using jQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Are there any jQuery/AJAX functions that when a form (or anything for that matter) is displayed, upon pressing a button the div containing the original form is replaced by a new form? Essentially, a multi-part form without having to reload the page.

Can I use something like this?

```
$('form#myForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: '',
            url: '',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) { 
                $('#divName').html(response); 
                //somehow repopulate div with a second form?
            }
        })
        return false;
 });
```

I've used this before for adding items to a list, but I've never used it to totally repopulate it with different content. How can I direct it to the second form?

**edit - I got it to work, but only when I write '#form2' for the replacement. I alerted the response and I get `{"formToShow":"show2"}`. I tried doing response.formToShow but it's undefined.**

```
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>


<div id="divName">
    <form method="POST" action = "#" id="form1">
        <input type="textbox" name="textbox1" value="1"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit1"/>
    </form>

    <form method="POST" action = "#" id="form2" style="display: none">
        <input type="textbox" name="textbox2" value="2"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit2"/>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
 $('form#form1').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'JSON',
            url: 'receiving.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) { 
                $('#form1').hide();  //hides
                //$('#form2').show();  //this will show
                $(response.formToShow).show(); //this does not display form 2
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Here is receiving.php. When I view this page `{"formToShow":"show2"}` is displayed

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array("formToShow" => "#form2"));
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you have the right idea... $('#divName').html(putformhere);

Comment: @DavidHoude do I reference the form's id where you have "putformhere"?

Comment: You would actually put your form code there, assuming that is the div where the old form was. When you use jQuery.html(string), it replaces whatever is in that div with the new content. Here, I was assuming your ajax response was another form (sent by the server in response to your first form)

Answer (score 1):

Check the [JQuery Load Function](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

This is personal preference, but I'd never send HTML through the response and display it like that, what I'd do is:

Send a JSON array back from the server, such as `{ formToShow: "#form1" }`

Then you can simply do this:

```
success: function(response) { 
   $('form').hide();
   $(response.formToShow).show();
}
```

Obviously, using this method, you'd also have to have the second form in your markup like this:

```
<form method="POST" action = "#" id="form2" style="display: none">
<input type="textbox" name="textbox2"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit2"/>
</form>
```

You'd also have to change (to pickup the array):

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'JSON'
```

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at it incorrectly, but it seems as if I wanted to add even a 3rd part this wouldn't work. How can I say upon success of the 2nd form, load a 3rd form?

Comment: Giving answers to just "what someone asks" isn't sometimes the best way of handling a scenario. I'm used to doing these operations on a daily basis, and this is the ideal way of doing it.

Comment: If anything, it's an easier way of achieving that @user1104854, send through the form type in your AJAX parameters and let the server send back the correct form ID to show. So, you send the second form ID through, the server tells the client to show the 3rd form.

Comment: @thedixon in that case, why hit the server at all?  (I agree, better to load all the html in one shot, but as I said, that's not at all what he's asking, and we don't know his architecture/reasoning for loading it via ajax)

Comment: @Nathan, that's very true, in this scenario there's no need to actually hit the server to hide/show the forms. I think, for me, it's to outline the control of HTML through array parameters, rather than full HTML replacement.

Comment: @thedixon I have it partially working. When I label the forms themselves in the success function (#form1.hide and #form2.show) it works. However, when I have it based on the response form2 will not show. I updated my code above.

Comment: Just an update, when I alert the response it shows {"formToShow":"show2"}. When I try response.formToShow it then says undefined.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. It must be because your service isn't sending the result back properly as a JSON response, make sure your response headers are JSON.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('form#myForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: '',
        url: '',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
        $('#divName').html(response); 
        $('#form1').hide();
        $('#form2').show();
        }
    })
    return false;
 });


<form method="POST" action = "#" id="form1">
    <input type="textbox" name="textbox1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1"/>
</form>

<form method="POST" action = "#" id="form2" style="dispay:none;">
    <input type="textbox" name="textbox2"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The two forms would be wrapped in div id= "divName", correct? I set type to POST and url to a php page I made. It displays both textboxes and buttons at the same time.

Comment: Can you provide what response you are getting after success?

Comment: I updated my code above. Form1 disappears but form2 doesn't appear.